# Element API SearchQuery to search for value inside child-entries

Tags: craft3, search, plugin-elementapi

I currently try to use the Element API to build a search. Unfortunately I'm kind of stuck.

I have a `baseEntry`, that has a field that references entries (let's call them `subEntries`) of the section `subEntries`, where `subEntries` have a field that references other entries (let's call those `categoryEntries`), where `categoryEntries` (for simplicity) only have a `title`.

Now I'm trying to output all `baseEntry`s that contain one ore more `subEntry`s which have one or more `categoryEntry`s with the title of my query... I tried to do this via `endpoint.json?section=baseEntry&q=subEntryHandleFromBaseEntry:*:categoryEntryHandleFromSubEntry:mySearchTerm` but that didn't work using

```
'endpoint.json' => function() {
    return [
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'paginate' => false,
        'one' => true,
        'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {

            $items = [];
            $section = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getParam('section');
            $param = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getParam('q');
            if ($param && $section) {


                $entries = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
                ->search($param)
                ->section($section)
                ->all();

                foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                    $items[] = UrlHelper::url("{$entry->type->handle}/{$entry->id}.json");
                }
            }

            return [
                $items
            ];
        },
    ];
},
```

as endpoint.

Also tried narrowing it down like:

```
$entries = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
->section($section)
->all();

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $items = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
    ->search($param)
    ->relatedTo($entry)
    ->all();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $items[] = UrlHelper::url("{$item->type->handle}/{$item->id}.json");
    }
}
```

didnt work either. I'm kind of lost. I'm looking into the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#relatedto) but can't seem to get it working.